# Configuring a XA datasource to mysql 8 DB with spring-boot and bitronix JTA manager fails with SqlException XAERR_RMERR

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa, jta, xa, bitronix

I have created a Spring Boot 2 (2.1.6.RELEASE) project with dependencies on spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and spring spring-boot-starter-jta-bitronix with a XA datasource configured for Mysql DB (8.0.16).

The application property file (trimmed for relevance with placeholder values between <>) contains the following configuration:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<dbName>
    username: <username>
    password: <password>
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
  jta:
    bitronix:
      properties:
        server-id: <serverid>
```

On starting the spring boot application, I received the error stacktrace below:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is bitronix.tm.resource.ResourceConfigurationException: cannot create JDBC datasource named dataSource
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is bitronix.tm.resource.ResourceConfigurationException: cannot create JDBC datasource named dataSource
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is bitronix.tm.resource.ResourceConfigurationException: cannot create JDBC datasource named dataSource
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is bitronix.tm.resource.ResourceConfigurationException: cannot create JDBC datasource named dataSource
Caused by: bitronix.tm.resource.ResourceConfigurationException: cannot create JDBC datasource named dataSource
Caused by: bitronix.tm.recovery.RecoveryException: failed recovering resource dataSource
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXAException: XAER_RMERR: Fatal error occurred in the transaction branch - check your data for consistency
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: XAER_RMERR: Fatal error occurred in the transaction branch - check your data for consistency
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I am self documenting my own question in hope of helping others as surprisingly this question / issue was quite obscure to resolve.**

From verifying the bitronix issue tracker on github https://github.com/bitronix/btm/issues/100, it was not very obvious on what the resolution was even though the issue was already closed without a direct answer.

Reading the bitronix FAQ at [https://github.com/bitronix/btm/wiki/FAQ](https://github.com/bitronix/btm/wiki/FAQ#why-is-oracle-throwing-a-xaexception-during-initialization-of-my-datasource) gave a hint on the issue though pertaining to Oracle which refers to missing user privileges.

Further investigation led to the MySQL 8 documentation page on privileges [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_xa-recover-admin) with a special highlight on the following section.

> Prior to MySQL 8.0, any user could execute the XA RECOVER statement to
>   discover the XID values for outstanding prepared XA transactions,
>   possibly leading to commit or rollback of an XA transaction by a user
>   other than the one who started it. **In MySQL 8.0, XA RECOVER is
>   permitted only to users who have the XA_RECOVER_ADMIN privilege, which
>   is expected to be granted only to administrative users who have need
>   for it.** This might be the case, for example, for administrators of an
>   XA application if it has crashed and it is necessary to find
>   outstanding transactions started by the application so they can be
>   rolled back. This privilege requirement prevents users from
>   discovering the XID values for outstanding prepared XA transactions
>   other than their own. It does not affect normal commit or rollback of
>   an XA transaction because the user who started it knows its XID.

Therefore, I added the required privilege to the datasource user through the following commands in MySQL (*Replace username and host section as appropriate*).

```sql
GRANT XA_RECOVER_ADMIN ON *.* TO 'username'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

With this change, the spring boot application starts without any issue.

Comment: Using WildFly 17 and MySQL 8 with XA datasources, we had ARJUNA016027 and ARJUNA016009 warnings logged every two minutes despite the application starting normally. Granting the XA_RECOVER_ADMIN role to the XA datasource user made them disappear.